# Stdin and Stdout

Tags: python

Can someone explain stdin and stdout? I don't understand what is the difference between using these two objects for user input and output as opposed to `print` and `raw_input`. Perhaps there is some vital information I am missing. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdin` and `stdout` are the streams for your operating system's standard input and output.

You use them to read and write data from your operating system's std input (usually keyboard) and output (your screen, the python console, or such).

`print` is simply a function which writes to the operting system's `stdout` and adds a newline to the end.
There are more features in `print` than just this, but that's the basic idea.

```
# Simplified print implementation
def print(value, end='\n'):
    stdout.write(value)
    stdout.write(end)
```

Answer (score 1):

`stdin` and `stdout` are stream representations of the standard in- and output that your OS supplies Python with.

You can do almost everything you can do with a file on these, so for many applications, they are far more useful than eg. `print`, which adds linebreaks etc.

Comment: And are they just for console input and output, or can they be used with files and pipes? If so how is that done? Can one use `stdin` and `stdout` in a Java program per say and then access this data in Python?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi They are for the console. Write the stuff to a file in Java, and then read (or write) it on python using `file()`.

Comment: And why do people pass `stdin` and `stdout` in Python subprocesses? What does that do?

Comment: Having these streams available in subprocesses that otherwise might have no access to your standard in/output ?!

Comment: Straight from the docs: `p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)`

Comment: read these docs further, they *explain* what the `stdin`/`stdout` *parameters* do -- they are not necessarily identical to `stdout`/`stdin` as in the `sys` module.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The `stdin` and `stdout` in your example are only names for the arguments, sure I can call anything nearly anything: `def stdin(stdout): print(stdout * 2)`, but these `stdin` and `stdout` are completely unrelated to the ones in the `sys` module.