# understanding what Docker stdin and stdout mean

Tags: docker

I was just going through `Docker run` documentation and came across the following command:

```
docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

The documentation can be found **[HERE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)**.

can somebody tell me, is the `stdin` and `stdout` stand for ?

I found this thread **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460426/stdin-and-stdout)**, but its related to python , can anybody explain this to me in the context of Docker and ofcourse ubuntu ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In general they are same as what you have mentioned and read in reference links for python. streams for receiving or reading input (stdin) and printing output (stdout). Example  input from the keyboard or printing output to unix terminal. one reference [here](https://linux.startcom.org/docs/fr/Introduction%20to%20Linux/sect_05_01.html).

By default docker attaches all streams to docker container (in foreground mode). If you choose to override say, in below command I only attach `stdout`

```
docker run -a stdout -i -t centos /bin/bash
```

This will only attach to stdout and hence I will not be able to type anything on this terminal, but could see print(input and output) from other terminal session of docker container (example when we login to docker container using command : `docker attach <container-id>`).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the default is to attach all streams. This wasn't clear to me at all from the documentation so I kept wondering why I was able to interact with the containers and get output without including -a flag.